# Counting total access to the list during the quicksort by Python

Tags: python, count, iteration, quicksort

I have the assignment to calculate the total number of list visits in the quick-sort program by Python.
Please check the code below:

```
arr1 = [4, 5, 3, 7, 2]
def inplace_quick_sort(arr, a, b, y):
    count = y
    count += 1  # for the access to the "a" element in the list while calling the function
    if a >= b:
        return

    count += 1  # access for arr[b]
    pivot = arr[b]
    left = a
    right = b - 1
    while left <= right:

        count += 1  # access for arr[left]
        while left <= right and arr[left] <= pivot:
            left += 1

        count += 1  # access for arr[right]
        while left <= right and pivot < arr[right]:
            right -= 1

        if left <= right:
            count += 4  # access for swap left and right
            arr[left], arr[right] = arr[right], arr[left]
            left, right = left + 1, right - 1

    count += 4  # access for swap left and last
    print(count)
    arr[left], arr[b] = arr[b], arr[left]
    inplace_quick_sort(arr, a, left - 1, count)
    inplace_quick_sort(arr, left + 1, b, count)

x = 0
print("count = " + str(inplace_quick_sort(arr1, 0, len(arr1) - 1, x)))
```

I have two questions.
The first is the "count" add the numbers for the list-visit correctly?
The second is I got a wired output like below:

```
count = 8
```

I do not understand the iteration about the "count." Why did  "count" equal to 8? The "count" suppose to be greater than 8.
Sorry, I made some mistakes in my code.
I revised it and still got the wired output.
I appreciate any guidance from you. Thank you very much.

Comment: You didn't return anything from the function, so what exactly are you printing as your "count"? Try "return count" at the end of the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main changes you need, to count array access correctly are:

1. Keep **`count` as a global variable** so that each branch of `inplace_quick_sort()` towards the end of your function updates the same counter. Remove `y` from the function definition and usage and start the main func with `global count`.
2. The two `count += 1`'s just before `while` should be just inside/at the start of each `while` loop because each while loop is accessing either `arr[left]` or `arr[right]`. So that counter should increment for each iteration of the `while`
3. For the statements `while left <= right and arr[left] <= pivot`, it's not necessary that `arr[left]` is accessed - if `left <= right` is False, then `arr[left] <= pivot` is never evaluated, and `arr[left]` is not accessed. That has to be split out into a different step:
4. This line should be removed because `a` is being accessed only once when you call it. The remaining times, it's recursive so update `coun`t there.

   - `count += 1  # for the access to the "a" element in the list while calling the function`
5. If array "access" includes only reading but not writing, then the two `count += 4` lines should be just `count += 2`. I've left it as per your code, change it accordingly or leave it as is.

```py
def inplace_quick_sort(arr, a, b):
    global count
    if a >= b:
        return

    count += 1  # access for arr[b]
    pivot = arr[b]
    left = a
    right = b - 1
    while left <= right:

        while left <= right:
            count += 1  # access for arr[left]
            if arr[left] <= pivot:
                left += 1
            else:
                break  # needed to match the original while-logic

        while left <= right:
            count += 1  # access for arr[right]
            if pivot < arr[right]:
                right -= 1
            else:
                break  # needed to match the original while-logic

        if left <= right:
            count += 4  # access for swap left and right
            arr[left], arr[right] = arr[right], arr[left]
            left, right = left + 1, right - 1

    count += 4  # access for swap left and last
    # print(count)
    arr[left], arr[b] = arr[b], arr[left]
    inplace_quick_sort(arr, a, left - 1)
    inplace_quick_sort(arr, left + 1, b)
```

Execute with:

```py
arr1 = [4, 5, 3, 7, 2]
count = 1  # because you sart with `len(arr1)`
inplace_quick_sort(arr1, 0, len(arr1) - 1)
print("count = ", count)
print('array afer:', arr1)
```

Output:

```
count =  30
array afer: [2, 3, 4, 5, 7]
```

---

Btw, if you did want to use `count` as a local variable, then:

- apply the changes mentioned above, but skip #1.
- the `if a >= b: return` statement should be `if a >= b: return count`
- each call to `inplace_quick_sort` should increment the previous `count` and make sure to `return count` at the end:

  - ```py
    count = inplace_quick_sort(arr, a, left - 1, count)
    count = inplace_quick_sort(arr, left + 1, b, count)
    return count
    ```

Also, this answer is only wrt `count`ing correctly, not fixing the implementation of quick sort as done.

Comment: Thank you very much.